# Sticking a large mirror on closet door

Tags: closet, mirror, rental

I live in a rental apartment and I just got a 12.6kg/28lb mirror that I would like to stick to my glass sliding closet door. Previously I would use a bunch of the 3M velcro command strips, but those only carry up to 20lb.
Is there a way to safely hang the mirror on the closet door without damaging the door when I eventually remove the mirror?
I was looking at the double-sided gorilla tape that takes up to 40lbs, but I'm not sure how easy that will be to remove.
Any advice?

Comment: @crip659 Glass...so can't drill it, hooks over the top are the likely answer - write it up and +1.

Answer (score 1):

For something that has a good chance of breaking if it falls, I would prefer solid hooks over the door, than trust tape alone.

I am not sure what is available for hooks or what you would like, but something that will hook over the door and screw to the mirror frame.

Maybe a pair of hooks(or similar devices) that you can attach a nice looking chain.

Tape is good for somethings, but with weight, the conditions must be perfect for best holding power.  If for any reason the tape lets go, you have seven years of bad luck, and a mess to clean up.

Comment: Yep, without knowing the operation of the sliding door, hard to make recs for hooks.  Does the door have rollers on the bottom?  Hang from rollers on a track at the top?  How much of a gap is there between door and frame?